I can't access tenant('id') in TenancyForLaravel
I am developing a multi-tenant app using TenancyForLaravel. Everything works till yesterday, I can't remember doing anything that must have changed the way the app works. Now, I'm trying to access tenant('id) on the AppServiceProvider.php file and the tenant.php route file and it keeps returning null. I can access a tenant on the domain abc.example.test and bcd.example.test, and I can also access tenant('id') on blade files, component files (livewire) and controller files.
I tried running dd(Tenant::all(), Domain::all()) in the AppServiceProvder and tenant.php file, it executed without issues, indicating that I have two tenants registered. I have cleared application cache but I'm still facing this issue. I have checked if anything is wrong with the configuration I did, I can't find any issues.
Laravel Framework: 11.9
TenancyForLaravel: 3.8.5

Please, I need help.

Please check in your setup
Use Middleware in routes:
// routes/tenant.php
Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    // Your routes here
});

Fix for AppServiceProvider:
public function boot()
{
    if (tenancy()->initialized) {
        $tenant = tenant();
        // you can access tenant('id')
    }
}

If still not working then clear the config and cache:
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear


I did as suggested, it is still the same. tenancy()->initialized is not true until it hits the livewire components and it was not so before now.

OR you can register TenancyServiceProvider first in app.php

Yes, I have tried that before now. I really don't understand why it is initializing so late.
